# Interpreting YOLOv8's Detection of E.coli Droplets on Leaves: A Grad-CAM Analysis

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, yolov8, pywavelets, gradcam

I'm working on a project where I trained a YOLOv8 model to find E.coli bacteria droplets on leaves. After using Grad-CAM on the YOLO model, which was 100% accurate, I noticed something unexpected. The areas without droplets are marked in red, and the areas with droplets are in blue, which means they're considered less important.

**Does this mean the model is actually working well and just the color scheme is flipped, or did I make a mistake somewhere?**

[image]
  [image]

In-depth info about data: The study utilizes fluorescence images of citrus fruits artificially inoculated with varying concentrations of E.coli bacteria. These images were processed using the PyWavelets Python module to apply wavelet transformations for enhancing image detail. After evaluating multiple wavelets, the Rbio1.3 wavelet was selected for its superior performance in maximizing the Peak Signal-to-Noise Ratio (PSNR), thereby facilitating more accurate model training and analysis.

Comment: polarity may simply have been chosen randomly by the network. it doesn't have to mean anything. perhaps it detects background (easy) and then uses that response to suppress the background.

Comment: Resolved!! 
The issue stemmed from mixing OpenCV (BGR) and PIL (RGB) without converting between formats. Solved by converting images to RGB with cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) before processing.